# Add external antenna to router with only internal antennas?

Tags: wifi, antenna, routing

Does anyone know if its possible to add an external antenna to a router with only internal antennas? I'm trying to improve the signal of my Linksys e4200v2. I'd like to add a high gain antenna if possible. Hopefully this would apply to a few of my Linksys WRT160N's that I'm using as client bridges. I saw some kits on eBay to add an antenna but I'm not sure how legit it was.

Comment: Our site is for design questions, not for consumer electronics support, sorry.

Comment: @Kortuk - If it was a plug-in aerial request it would be a shopping questiion. As it is it's a design one.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I see a user asking if they can add an external antenna to a consumer device, if you think I have misread can you clean up the question with an edit a little to make it on topic?

Comment: Sorry about that Russell. I wasn't exactly sure where to post. Would SuperUser be a better spot or does StackExchange not really deal with these type of questions?

Comment: @StoneFX - can you provide a link to the ebay kits - I may be able to comment and/or advise re modifying the question to make it suitable.

Comment: [This looks legitimate at $16.99](http://www.ebay.com/itm/7dBi-Antenna-Mod-Kit-Linksys-WRT160N-all-versions-Linksys-E1000-/110899877369?_trksid=p4340.m1850&_trkparms=aid%3D222002%26algo%3DSIC.FIT%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D11%26meid%3D1778107676267351723%26pid%3D100011%26prg%3D1005%26rk%3D1%26) as does [**this**](http://www.ebay.com/itm/7dBi-Antenna-Mod-Kit-WRT610N-v-2-no-soldering-/350463132417) at $19.99 . This is what I expected a mod to have to do - any one solution may be good or not but they are doing the right sort of thing - external SMA connected aerilas attached to where original aerials went.

Comment: @Kortuk - see links. Something of a grey area. The kits are effectively buy & fit BUT require removal of old connections and soldering in new parts. There is scope for improving or doing your own this way.